# What is the difference between $|x|$ and $\|x\|$?

Tags: geometry, notation

I'm taking my **first course of Analytical Geometry in college** and I would like to have some clarification regarding this notation.

Wikipedia mentions that $|x|$ denotes *Norm* in general, a concept that apparently arises in many mathematical fields and also mentions that $\|x\|$ refers to the *Euclidean Norm*, so my question is:

> Is this their common use? Are they interchangeable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\|\cdot\|$ notes most of the time a norm which is defined, or is clear. $|\cdot|$ is most of the time just the absolut value.

Comment: And no, they mean different things most of the time For $(x_1,x_2)=x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ it is $\|x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$

Comment: Some authors use $\lvert\bullet\rvert$ for the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and $\lVert\bullet\rVert$ for a norm on a more general vector space. But it boils down to personal preference. For some authors they may even be interchangeable.

Comment: You can check out this post with answers. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707269/what-does-this-double-absolute-value-like-notation-mean/1707280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of norms,
and,
in my experience,
either notation can be used
for any of them.
Some typical ones are
$\sum |x_i|,
\sqrt{\sum x_i^2},
(\sum |x_i^p|)^{1/p},
\max(|x_i|)
$.

You can put a normalizing factor
such as $\frac1{n}$,
where $n$ is the number of elements,
in front of any form
that sums over the elements.